# TermServDevices Event ID 1111

Tags: windows-server-2003

I am running Server 2003 R2 Standard SP2, and I continually get a TermServDevices Event ID 1111 error. The server is only used as a File Server and the only authentication required of end users is for access to folders. There are no other services being used on this server. We do not have a domain, only a local workgroup. Most printers are installed locally via USB and shared, but we do have some that are network printers but not managed by the server. Those drivers are installed on the client PC's using the printer.

Each time the error is generated, it generates 10 errors for various printers installed on cliant PC's (XP and Vista) on our workgroup. It also generates errors for MS XPS Document Writer, MS OneNote Writer, MS Office Document Image Writer and MS Shared Fax Driver.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You presumably have Terminal services enabled in Remote Administration mode, and your administrators are using this to log into the server. The event just says that TS doesn't have the printer drivers installed to enable printer redirection to the TS sessions.

You can disable local printer support on the Server (Start/Admin tools/Terminal Services Configuration) to avoid the event log getting cluttered, but it's not doing any harm.

Of course, if no-one you know about is logging into your server that's a good time to start worrying :-)

JR

Comment: +1 for disabling local printer mapping on servers where it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

In general whenever you try to take RDP of any server it try to map the printers installed in you desktop machine (Source), so due to mismatch of the printers its through the error, just follow the below steps to avoid error event ID 1111

Just go to start->Administrative tools->Terminal services configuration->Double click on Rdp-Tcp->Client settings->Select Windows printer mapping->Apply-OK. try to re login to server through RDP  now you can find there will be no errors related to printer.